# How to mount volume to /var

Tags: terraform, openstack

I want */var* to be on a separate volume. The image (provided by the OpenStack provider) contains a single partition.

I can easily attach a volume to a new empty path like */opt/blah*. But how to attach a volume to the already existing */var* and keep the data on it?

Comment: There's no magic here: you mount the new filesystem at a temporary location, copy over the files, and then remount the filesystem onto your target (`/var`). Note that this can be tricky because files in `/var` are often in use, so this will generally require a reboot to be effective. Don't forget to update your `/etc/fstab`!

Comment: I assume I need to do it using cloud-init `runcmd`. Sounds unreliable and hacky :-(

Comment: I think you can also define mountpoints using cloud-init? https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/examples.html#adjust-mount-points-mounted

Comment: I assume this will not move existing content of /var to the volume(?)